# Polymer, template won't evaluate true and bind

Tags: javascript, html, templates, polymer, web-component

Using polymer I am very simply trying to evaluate wether an object property is a specific value, and if so bind the contents of truthy template to the dom.

I have:

```
<polymer-element name="template-elem">
  <template >
    <div>
    <template if={{response.data.type === "message"}}>
      <div>working</div>
    </template>
    </div>
  </template>
  <script>

    Polymer({
      response: {}, 
        ready: function(){
      this.response = {"data":{
        "type":"message",
        "detail":"default"
      }};
        },
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Also tried, == "message".  The template DOES bind if asked to evaluate a boolean expression, and `{{response.data.detail}}` displays the correct text.  I have tried this in two separate elements (starting from scratch) and the problem persists, can anyone tell me what I am clearly overlooking?

Also tried passing to a helper function `{{response | parseObj}}, {{item in response | parseObj}}, {{item in response.data | parseObj}}` and the function is never called.

Comment: When passing a function, did you actually call the function? `{{fnname()}}` Otherwise, it will simply check if the function exists.

Comment: Well according to polymer [docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/template.html) theres no need for `( )` for function execution.  It should see the function attached to this (element) and the `|` operator should pass in the arg to the left.  e.g `"{{item | parseObj}}"`

Comment: According to https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/expressions.html, there is in expressions that require a return for evaluations. That said, I'm glad @Dirk Grappendorf's answer solved it!

Comment: Oh okay, so you do have that option as well.  Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the quotation marks around the `if` attribute value. Try

```
<template if="{{response.data.type === 'message'}}">
```

Without the quotes, the browser (Chrome) parses this line as

```
<template if="{{response.data.type" =="=" 'message'}}=""></template>
```

Comment: Annnnd thats the problem exactly, guess thats what happens when I'm too tired!